# Is it possible to create a hologram using X-Rays?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, hologram

Is it possible to create a hologram using X-Rays (or other penetrating EM-waves)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, check some of the papers here:

> http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=x-ray+holography